# Generating sitemaps in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap-generator-gem

I am trying to generate a sitemap for my Rails app. I want to generate them on a periodic basis and not on every hit. I was previously using this to generate sitemaps https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator. This seems good for sitemaps under 50k urls. Now I want to create an index as well and divide my sitemaps based on page types that is all school pages will go into a `school` sitemap similarly for other pages like `student`, `sports` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with that same gem you mentioned. Please read [Generating multiple sitemaps](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator)

And if you want to set them to check only periodically you change the `<changefreq></changefreq>` to something like this: `<changefreq> monthly </changefreq>`

Answer (score -1):

Using the sitemap_generator gem will be the easiest way to do it.

Simply write your generation login in `sitemap.rb` file and run `rake sitemap:refresh` to create your sitemap for the first time.

After doing that, run this command whenever you like by writing it in the crontab or using a gem like whenever which provides a dsl for writing periodic commands using cron.